# Assembly cmp instruction that has 3 arguments

Tags: assembly

I am reading through some assembly code trying to figure out what its doing ( its a challenge so nothing malicious).
On a single line there is the following instruction :

cmp d,[eax],0DADADADA

I have spent ages on Google and cant figure this one out, i know you can't compare 3 values so i know the 0DA.... part is what I'm missing. I found some article that i cannot find again suggesting that this is something to do with filling up blank memory but not sure, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is pretty suspicious. `cmp` has exactly 2 input operands, and it implicitly sets the status flags as the only output. Plus, that `0DADADADA` looks bad as well: The leading zero should identify it as an octal number, while the digits are obviously hexadecimal.

Comment: The leading zero identifies it as a number; whether it is octal or not is a matter of definition of the assembler, and this is clearly a hex constant.

Comment: @IraBaxter: Well, commonly hex literals are prefixed with `0x...`, while octal ones have a leading zero. This question *might* relate to an assembler that uses different conventions, but the exact assembler isn't mentioned.

Comment: @EOF: "The exact assembler isn't mentioned". And that is entirely the point.

Comment: @IraBaxter: ...and in that case I'll assume normal conventions, and mention that this is odd.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the assembler syntax you are using; there's quite a number of varieties for the x86 (which this likely is) and even for others.

Not knowing the specific syntax, and agreeing that CMP instructions don't have 3 operands, I'm guessing the "d" means "dword [32 bits]".   So  I think the likely interpretation is

```
   "compare  dword operand indirect through eax to hex literal 0DADADADA"
```

That is a valid x86 instruction.

Comment: Perhaps somewhere further up there's a macro defining `d` as `DWORD` ?

Comment: I'm afraid i cant answer anything of that because i just don't know. We have just been provided with a snippet of code ( 10 lines ) and we just have try and figure out what that portion is doing. Nothing in the code is defining what 'd' is .

Comment: Provided by who?  It is one thing to ask you understand something where the something is clearly defined and you are learning the details of such a definition.  It is entirely another thing to have somebody hand you something without making the definitions behind it clear.  I assume the agent asking is professor?  Either he is teaching you a lesson in the real world (when you don't get enough information, it is *your* problem to get enough), or he's a very bad teacher.  If not, he's a clueless boss, welcome to the real world.  I'd ask him point blank specifically which assembler notation.

Comment: yeah i think ill ask the person to give me more info. Thanks again