# invalid operand in cmp byte ptr

Tags: assembly, disassembly, fasm

I tried to run this code, but FASM told me that it is invalid operand in `cmp b....`

```
00000000: B80300     mov  ax,00003
00000003: CD10       int  010
00000005: B402       mov  ah,002
00000007: 8B167501   mov  dx,[0175]
0000000B: CD10       int  010
0000000D: FEC6       inc  dh
0000000F: 80C203     add  dl,003
00000012: 89167501   mov  [0175],dx
00000016: B409       mov  ah,009
00000018: BA5001     mov  dx,00150
0000001B: CD21       int  021
0000001D: 803E760119 cmp  b,[0176],019 // invalid operand
00000022: 75E1       jne  000000005
00000024: B410       mov  ah,010
00000026: CD16       int  016
00000028: CD20       int  020
```

What's the problem ?

Comment: `cmp` takes two operands and not three. It looks like x86 disassembly, but what disassembler would produce that?

Comment: i rewrite `cmp byte ptr [176],19`. It says `invalid expression`.

Comment: I put `803E760119` in a disassembler and the result was `cmp byte [0176h], 019h`.

Comment: [Here at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27176284/1305969) seems to be a similar question.

Comment: Thanks. Turned out that FASM `cmp  byte [0176], 019` == `cmp  byte ptr 0176, 019 `

Comment: What disassembler do you use ?)

Comment: [I used ODA](https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/) and converted the output to FASM syntax.